# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'css'. Trying to scrape old reddit but geting this error

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, reddit

I'm trying to scrape the [old reddit](https://old.reddit.com/) but every time I get this error:

```
>>> response.css('div')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'css'
```

Am I doing something wrong or can you not scrape the old reddit?

This is the log:

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://old.reddit.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-11-02 14:56:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://old.reddit.com/> from <GET http://old.reddit.com>
2020-11-02 14:56:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://old.reddit.com/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you received an empty response (`None`). So you are trying to call the `.css()` method in a empty variable. The reason why you received `None` and not the expected response object is because **your spider filtered the request**.

You can see in this line of your execution log:

```
2020-11-02 14:56:09 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://old.reddit.com/>
```

The requested URL is not allowed by the site's `robots.txt`. You can disable this filter by changing in your spider's `settings.py` in the line `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY`. To disable it use:

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

**This will cause your spider to ignore `robots.txt` for ALL requests.** ([Read more](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey))

However respecting the `robots.txt` rules is considered a good practice (even ethical one may say) in webscraping. More details on the `robots.txt` standard [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my scrapy shell output, Hope its help.

```
(scrapy_env) rana@rana-desktop:~/Documents/allproject/scrapy_projt/tutorial$
$ scrapy shell https://old.reddit.com/

In [2]: response.status
Out[2]: 200

In [3]: response.css('div')
Out[3]: 
[<Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="GoogleAd HomeAds InArticl...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div id="header" role="banner"><a tab...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div id="sr-header-area"><div class="...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="width-clip"><div class="d...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="dropdown srdrop" onclick=...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="drop-choices srdrop"><a h...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="sr-list"><ul class="flat-...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div id="header-bottom-left"><a href=...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div id="header-bottom-right"><span c...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="side"><div class="spacer"...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="spacer"><form action="htt...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div id="searchexpando" class="infoba...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div id="moresearchinfo"><p>use the f...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="spacer"><form method="pos...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="status"></div>'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div id="remember-me"><input type="ch...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="submit"><span class="thro...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="clear"></div>'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="spacer"><div class="sideb...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="sidebox submit submit-lin...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="morelink"><a href="https:...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="nub"></div>'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="spacer"><div class="sideb...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="sidebox submit submit-tex...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="morelink"><a href="https:...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="nub"></div>'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="spacer"><a href="/premium...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="premium-banner__logo"></div>'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="premium-banner__title">Ge...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="content" role="main"><sec...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="listingsignupbar__cta-con...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="spacer"><style type="text...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="happening-now-wrap"><div ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="happening-now"><div><p cl...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div><p class="icon"><img src="//www....'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="close-button">x</div>'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="spacer"><style>body >.con...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div id="siteTable" class="sitetable ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class=" thing id-t3_jmlqpj odd  ...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="midcol unvoted"><div clas...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="arrow up login-required a...'>,

 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="clearleft"></div>'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="nav-buttons"><span class=...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="footer-parent"><div by-ze...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div by-zero class="footer rounded"><...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="col"><ul class="flat-vert...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="col"><ul class="flat-vert...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="col"><ul class="flat-vert...'>,
 <Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::div' data='<div class="col"><ul class="flat-vert...'>]
```

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you though